# Rigidbody2D moves on x axis without adding force

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

I'm currently trying to learn some Physics2D in Unity. Now, I've created a Ball (sprite) and added a RigidBody2D and a CircleCollider2D on it.

The RigidBody2D has the following settings:

- Bodytype: Dynamic
- Simulated: true
- Use Auto Mass: false
- Mass: 1
- Linear Drag: 0
- Angular Drag: 0
- Gravity Scale: 25
- Collision Detection: Continous
- Sleeping Mode: Start Awake
- Interpolate: None

Now, when I start the scene, the ball drops as expected. However, it's also moving on the x-axis by ~83 pixels, which I don't want. The movement on the x-axis stops once it reached that ~83 pixels point.

If I freeze the x-position in the Rigidbody2D-Settings I get the intended behaviour (ball just dropping on y-axis), but I feel like that would be a hack instead of fixing the actual problem.

What could cause this? I expected the ball to just drop, if I have no drag, a certain mass and gravity enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The object was colliding with the background it seems.

Comment: Next time, try to reproduce the problem in a new empty project first. That will ensure that the information/instructions you include in your question are sufficient to reproduce it and diagnose a cause, and will often help you isolate the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: Please accept your answer.